# Tomcat8 on OpenShift

Tags: tomcat, openshift, tomcat8, openshift-cartridge

Is there a Tomcat 8 cartridge for OpenShift? I know that you can install Tomcat8 in a DIY cartridge, but I was looking for a faster and easier solution.

And if there is one, how can I install it and how can I migrate an application from jbossews 2 (tomcat7)?

I tried to use https://github.com/openshift/origin-community-cartridges/tree/master/openshift-origin-cartridge-tomcat as a downloadable cartridge, but I got this error:

> The provided downloadable cartridge 'https://github.com/openshift/origin-community-cartridges/raw/master/openshift-origin-cartridge-tomcat/metadata/manifest.yml' cannot be loaded: Cartridge-Vendor 'Red Hat' does not match pattern /\Aa-z0-9\z/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like an old cartridge. The only explanation I can think of for the Cartridge-Vendor error is that Red Hat changed its validation for the field. All of their up-to-date [cartridges](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges) define

```
Cartridge-Vendor: redhat
```

without the space.

You may be able to hack around it by forking that git repo and changing the Cartridge-Vendor yourself. Only their manifest validation [logic](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/b06ff29c484ff4f7c611f4c02955128c06916bc3/common/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/manifest.rb) also prohibits using `redhat` as a vendor since it's reserved:

```
  reserved_vendor_names = %w(
    redhat
  )
```

So editing `manifest.yml` you may get this cartridge to work, but I wouldn't bet on it since the cartridge is no longer supported.

Comment: So, is there a cartridge for Tomcat8?

Comment: I don't believe so, but this is the closest I've seen to one. I think it's the best starting point you have to a working Tomcat 8 cart. I'd fork the repo and modify the manifest until the cartridge installs.