# OpenShift install Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, openshift, tomcat8

I am trying to install Tomcat 8 in OpenShift by following this  [tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-run-apache-tomcat-8-on-openshift/), but I am stuck in step:

> Next we need to remove the dependency of build-docs target from deploy target as it gives an exception
>
> ```
> target name="deploy" depends="package, build-tomcat-jdbc"
>           description="Default. Builds a working Tomcat instance"
> ```

I can't find out where to find this line to modify it, is it in **build.properties**?

Comment: Similar question was posed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149311/tomcat8-on-openshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line belongs to `build.xml` file, which is usually at the same location as `build.properties.default`, in `${tomcat.source}` folder.

More details on Tomcat building [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/building.html#Configure_download_area).

Comment: Thank's I will search for it now, but following the same tutorial I have to do ant clean, but it says command not found and even when I try to install it with apt get , the same error what's wrong !!!

Comment: I think this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592421/how-to-use-ant-to-compile-and-deploy-my-webapp-in-openshift-server it seems that ant was remove from DIY cartridge